# get a value from a json object (Google map distance)

Tags: java, android, json

hello I'm trying t get the distance from a JSON object

```
{
    "destination_addresses": [
        "Rabat, Morocco"
    ],
    "origin_addresses": [
        "Marrakesh, Morocco"
    ],
    "rows": [
        {
            "elements": [
                {
                    "distance": {
                        "text": "324 km",
                        "value": 323624
                    },
                    "duration": {
                        "text": "3 hours 24 mins",
                        "value": 12233
                    },
                    "status": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

I succeeded to get the elements object but I can't get the distance

> org.json.JSONException: No value for distance
>                     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>                     at com.application.zarbagaskazay.colivoiturage.testMApsActivity$1.onResponse(testMApsActivity.java:66)
>                     at com.application.zarbagaskazay.colivoiturage.testMApsActivity$1.onResponse(testMApsActivity.java:56)
>                     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)

here is the code

```
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                JSONArray rows = response.getJSONArray("rows");
                        JSONObject elements=rows.getJSONObject(0);
                   //  JSONObject cc=  elements.getJSONObject("distance");
                        System.out.println(elements.get("distance"));

                        button.setText(elements.get("distance").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my suggestion:

You can replace

System.out.println(elements.get("distance"));

with

**System.out.println(elements.getJSONArray("elements").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObj
ect("distance"));**

Above sop will print/extract "distance" json value.

{"text":"324 km","value":323624}

Hope it works at your end too!

Comment: thanks a lot it's really nested for me as a beginner thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("YOUR RESPONSE STRING");
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJsonArray("rows");
 JSONArray jsonArray_elements =jsonArray.getJsonObject(0).getJsonArray("elements");
 JSONObject jsonObject_distance = 
 jsonArray_elements.get(0).getJsonObject("distance");

 String text = jsonObject_distance.getString("text");
 String value = jsonObject_distance.getString("value");
```